# Javascript: onChange gives a "is undefined" error on IE - works for Chrome + FF

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I have been trying to find out why I keep getting an "is undefined" error on IE, for a web page I have been working on. I have been researching a possible issue for quite a while including looking at quite a few StackOverflow related questions with out any luck or success a finding a solution. I am hoping that someone may have come across a problem like this in the past and could help me out.

I have included the HTML/JavaScript code below. The error is from the select statement that says: `onchange="changeCat(this)"`.

Thanks for any help you can offer, as this problem should be simple, but yet it defies solution.

HTML Code:

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
...

function changeCat(mySelectName) {
    var selectName = mySelectName.name;

    var selectBox = document.getElementById(selectName);
    var selectedValue = selectBox.options[selectBox.selectedIndex].value;

    getCatResults (catUrl, selectedValue);

}

....

</script>

...

<div class="col-md-2 ">
   <select onchange="changeCat(this)" id="categoryID" name="categoryID">
      <option value="1">Unknown</option>
      <option value="2">Accounting</option>
      <option value="3">Management</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: `I keep getting an "is undefined" error on IE` - can you please specify which piece of code is triggering that error ... and what it is that `is undefined` ... surely IE gives far more information than jsut `is undefined`

Comment: Can you check exactly which statement on the changeCat function is throwing the error? (a simple way is to put some `console.log('step x')` before each statement on that function)

Comment: Which version of IE are you testing this under and what [document mode](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/internet-explorer/ie11-deploy-guide/deprecated-document-modes) is active?  If it's anything less than IE9 or a document mode earlier than IE9 standards mode, that's likely your problem.  [IE did not support](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/change.html) the DOM L3 version of onchange until IE9...and even then, the [implementation was (is) dicey](http://caniuse.com/#search=change).

Comment: Hi All .. Thanks for the help .. I don't even get to the changeCat function  as all IE gives is the "Is Undefined Message" - I am using IE 11.0.96 so it is fairly recent. I suspect that there something else that is causing the javascript functions to be undefined, but I can't find it - I was wondering if there was some form IE page checker - I tried JSLint but it didn't change anything. I didn't post the full web page is quite long, but I can send you the full page if you like I didn't want to polute the question with extraneous html code